# Adding a variable href attribute to a hyperlink using XSLT

Tags: xslt, nested

I need to create links using dynamic values for both the URL and the anchor text.

I have column called *URL*, which contains URL's, i.e., `http://stackoverflow.com`, and I have a column called *Title*, which contains the text for the anchor, i.e., `This Great Site`.

I figure maybe all I need to do is nest this tags, along with a little HTML to get my desired result:

```
<a href=">
    <xsl:value-of select="@URL">">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </xsl:value-of>
</a>
```

In my head, this would render:

```
<a href="
    http://stackoverflow.com">
        This Great Site
</a>
```

I know there's more to it, but I haven't been able to clearly understand what more I need. I think this issue has been addressed before, but not in a way I could understand it. I'd be more than happy to improve the question's title to help noobs like myself find this item, and hopefully an answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a sample of the input XML that is being transformed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing your XML, but you can use "Attribute Value Templates" here to create the `href` attribute.

```
<a href="{@URL}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>
```

The curly braces `{ }` indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

For complex expressions, or if you wanted to create attributes only for certain conditions, or with dynamic names, you could make use of the `xsl:attribute` element, like so

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
       <xsl:value-of select="@URL"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
</a>
```

Attribute Value Templates are generally preferred though.

Comment: Both the Attribute Value Template and the `xsl:attribute' methods work, and I've implemented the Attribute Value Template per your recommendation. Thank you so much for taking the time to share!

Do you have any recommendations for how I can improve the question's title or body to help others find this?

Cheers~

Comment: Maybe along the lines of "How to add a variable href attribute to a hyperlink using XSLT"?